# Variable initialization with internal variable

Tags: ksh, variable

How would I get this to work in ksh?

```
variable1="$(strings /.sh_history | grep '^\user' | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f2)"
variable2="$(command ${variable1})"
```

Basically, I would like to use variable1 as a string to use with a command to declare a variable.

UPDATE:  The issue was not actually related to my syntax. The error was due to the text being formatted which created an issue. I cut using the text modifiers as delimiters and was able successfully pull the data. I did use both of the advised solutions to make my script cleaner.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input and expected output.

Comment: variable1="$(strings /.sh_history | grep '^\user' | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f2)"

variable2="$(command ${variable1})"

Basically, I would like to use variable1 as a string to use with a command to declare a variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store shell code, use *functions*:

```
function1() { strings /.sh_history | grep "$@"; }
variable1=$(function1 foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval`:

```
variable1='strings /.sh_history | grep'
variable2=$(eval "$variable1 foo")
```